# Removing orphaned iTunes songs from hard drive

Tags: windows-7, itunes

Some times when I delete songs from iTunes it does not ask me if I also want to delete it from the hard drive.

As a result I have a bunch of songs that are taking up space in my hard drive that are not in iTunes.

I have over 3000 files, is there an automated way to find files on the hard drive that are NOT in iTunes?  I want to delete them so that they are not taking up space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the `iTunes Media folder location` (`Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Advanced`) and then use the `Consolidate files` function (`File` -> `Library` -> `Organise Library`).

This will copy everything to the new location without the orphans and you can then delete the old one.

Comment: If, like me, you want to keep some of those orphans (files recovered after accidental deletion), you can use a diff utility (EG *Beyond Compare*) between the new folder and the old to identify them.

Comment: **WARNING:** If you have: multiple iTunes profiles on your machine, or batch files, or use utilities like `itunes_open_library.exe` or custom Python scripts, etc.; this approach will: **scramble your libraries together** and **trash your carefully organized folders** and mandate edits and reworks of all your batch files, scripts, and utilities.

Comment: I kinda think that if you are the type of person who has any of that stuff, you probably won't be needing to use this method in the first place!